# Woocommerce REST API Status: 401 - Invalid signature - provided signature does not match

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Hello I am using WooCommerce API - Node.js Client https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api

And I am trying to create a customer which requires a POST request to the server.
Here is the code to initialize woocomerece REST API:

```
var WooCommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api');

var WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'http://example.com',
  consumerKey: 'ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  consumerSecret: 'cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  wpAPI: true,
  version: 'wc/v1'
});
```

This is the code to Create customer:

```
  var data = {
  email: 'john.doe@example.com',
  first_name: 'John',
  last_name: 'Doe',
  username: 'john.doe',
  billing: {
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Doe',
    company: '',
    address_1: '969 Market',
    address_2: '',
    city: 'San Francisco',
    state: 'CA',
    postcode: '94103',
    country: 'US',
    email: 'john.doe@example.com',
    phone: '(555) 555-5555'
  },
  shipping: {
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Doe',
    company: '',
    address_1: '969 Market',
    address_2: '',
    city: 'San Francisco',
    state: 'CA',
    postcode: '94103',
    country: 'US'
  }
};

WooCommerce.post('customers', data, function(err, data, res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

But I keep getting the following response from server.

```
{
"code":"woocommerce_rest_authentication_error",
"message":"Invalid signature - provided signature does not match.",
"data":{"status":401}
}
```

However any GET request to the works on the server eg: I can get the list of products.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: @minnow Yes, I used 'https' instead of 'http'. I could not perform any POST requests using 'http'

Comment: Thanks for responding. Not want I wanted to hear, though. I'm already using https, but same result: GETs work just fine, but not POST. For the GETs, I have to use oAuth1.0a. Basic Auth doesn't work.

Comment: @minnow Interesting for me Basic Auth works for GET and POST when I used HTTPS, Did you try changing the version to `version: 'wc/v2` ?

Comment: Yes, I was already using https

Comment: @minnow you got solution of this problem . i am getting the same problem

Comment: No, unfortunately not @MukulSharma

Comment: try adding "www." to your url.

Comment: Worked for me after using query_string_auth = True with the python wrapper

Comment: Did you guys find the problem when using http? In my case sometimes it works, sometimes it says "invalid signature"... completely random.

Answer (score 4):

As the error is self explanatory. This is clearly an authentication issue. It's clearly mention in the documentation

**Over HTTPS**

You may use HTTP Basic Auth by providing the API Consumer Key as the username and the API Consumer Secret as the password.

**Over HTTP**

You must use OAuth 1.0a "one-legged" authentication to ensure API credentials cannot be intercepted.

For more detail you can refer the documentation at [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v3.html?shell#authentication)

Comment: in other words, your url needs to be 'https' not 'http'

Comment: Documentation says it should be https

Answer (score 2):

### Error with Postman (but could apply to any)

I finally discovered that the issue was a final trailing slash to the Host I provided to PostMan.

To understand what url the website was based of after so much time waste I went to **Settings -> General Settings**: **WordPress Address (URL) & Site Address (URL)**

[image]

Hence I took the correct host from there.

In Post man then I used Aouth.1 making sure that is set to **Request Boddy / Request URL**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. make sure `url: 'http://example.com'` matches exactly the one you have in wordpress general setting page. for example both start with `www` and have the exact protocol of `https`

Answer (score 0):

The header must contain key "Content-Type": "application/json"

I am using the OAuthRequest, where it is coded by:

```
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

It works for me fine even with HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I found the issue was due to the URL used on Postman is using www., but under WordPress > General Settings on both WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) was set without www. So, it makes sense that the signature is invalid.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error occurred because I was using the `desktop app` trying to access `https://` and I fixed by turning off `SSL certificate verification` by the following:

File > Settings

[image]

Then `SSL certificate verification` to off

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In the object you are passing through to the functions (var data) your key also need to be a string.

eg.

var data = {
"first_name": "Joe"
//and so on

}